# How to configure logrotate to just prune a directory once a week?

Tags: cron, logrotate

How to configure logrotate to just delete all files under selected directory once a week?

I'm testing the following:

> /var/spool/mydir/* {
>
> ```
>     daily
>     rotate 0
>     nocompress
>     copytruncate }
> ```

But it doesn't seem to remove anything. Should I wait one day?

Thank you.

Comment: You wanted to prune a directory one a week, but you specified daily. Did you mean to specify weekly in the config file?